# Alternative to EV_TIMEOUT in eiffel?

Tags: timer, eiffel

Is there any alternative to `EV_TIMEOUT` in [Eiffel](http://docs.eiffel.com/static/libraries/vision2/ev_timeout_flatshort.html)?  this looks like is only for windows application since there is not option to add this library into the project..

thanks in advance >)

Comment: Are you interested in performing the same sequence of steps in a console application or in a GUI application on a non-Windows platform?

Comment: In a GUI application. (any difference from doing so in a console application while testing?) :) wow thanks for the reply @kwaxer

Comment: EV_TIMEOUT is part of the EiffelVision library, the portable graphical library for Eiffel. So you just need to include the EiffelVision library to your project and you will have access to this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Emmanuel Stapf comment is the answer.

> EV_TIMEOUT is part of the EiffelVision library, the portable graphical library for Eiffel. So you just need to include the EiffelVision library to your project and you will have access to this class

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didnt find any way to do that, `EV_TIMEOUT` only works in GUI level, so just created a loop and keep looping for ever :)